# How to handle strings containing HTML using Angular Translate?

Tags: angularjs

I've seen a lot of topics about this problem, but it hasn't resolved my problem. When I try to use

```
<p ng-html-bind-unsafe="{{tasksDetails[task.id].description | translate:{task:task, taskDetails:tasksDetails[task.id]} }}"></p>
```

nothing appears at the website. The primary way to display it was:

```
<label data-translate>TASK_DETAILS</label> <label class="value-label">{{tasksDetails[task.id].description | translate:{task:task, taskDetails:tasksDetails[task.id]} }}</label>
```

but it doesn't recognize html tags.

Comment: While it is possible, angular is not built to have html in the model. Angular tries to enforce a MVC structure with client-side templates, erasing the need for stitching together dynamic html yourself. So I would rehtink your design

Comment: So, is there any possibility to change </br> to enters using angular? or it's not possible